# Use constraint generic with interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface, constraints

I have the following code where generic are involved :

```
    public class MyWorkerClass<T> : IWorkerContract<T> //in IWorkerContract also i have same generic constraint that i have in this class.
      where T: INeedAction, new()
    {
        public void DoWork ( T item )
        {
             //Loop on each property of item...
             if ( ..if current property value implement from INeedAction, then condition for recursion.. )
             {
                  this.DoWork ( currentPropertyValue as INeedAction);
                  //Get error -> "Can not convert INeedAction to T"
             }
```

Basically i have a woker that operate on an object 'A' (that need to implement the interface INeedAction).
If any property of that object 'A' implement the same interface of the object itself (the i INeedAction interface) then i need to recurse with the same DoWork logic on that property too.

Strangelly i get that error that i does not understand : "Can not convert INeedAction to T"
Why this, if i enforced that T must implement INeedAction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that `Foo` and `Bar` both implement `INeedAction`, and `Foo` has a property of type `Bar`.

Then a `MyWorkerClass<Foo>` represents a work that is able to `DoWork` on a `Foo`. So far so good. However, look what happens when `DoWork` is called and it finds the `Bar` property. Since `Bar` implements `INeedAction`, you call

```
this.DoWork (bar as INeedAction);
```

Remember that `this` is still `MyWorkerClass<Foo>` - a thing that can only do work on `Foo`, but you are giving it a `Bar` to work with! That doesn't make sense, does it? This is why you can't pass an `INeedWork` to a parameter accepting `T`.

Note also that `DoWork` is not generic. It accepts a very specific type - `T`. This has to be the same `T` that is used in the class's type parameter.

---

Judging from your code, I don't think `DoWork` should be generic at all. It should accept an `INeedWork`.

Comment: Yes you are right, changing the signature so that it accept only INeedWork is simpler and work as intended.
Thanks again for the clarification